# Why is apiKeyRequired = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE not enforced?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am building GAE standard endpoint with Java using Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
        <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
        <version>${endpoints.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

where

```
    <endpoints.framework.version>2.0.9</endpoints.framework.version>
```

Annotating API with:

```
 @Api( name = "blah", 
       version = "v1", 
       apiKeyRequired = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE,

 @ApiMethod( name = "taxdocument.store", 
             path = "taxdoc/store", 
             httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST )
```

But API is not enforcing API keys.

Perhaps I am not understanding. I am expecting that POST to this would work.

```
https://blah.appspot.com/_ah/api/blah/v1/taxdoc/store?key=valid-key
```

But this would fail

```
https://blah.appspot.com/_ah/api/blah/v1/taxdoc/store?key=invalid-key
https://blah.appspot.com/_ah/api/blah/v1/taxdoc/store
```

But ALL succeed with no errors.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the [API management library and filters](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management).

Comment: That was the missing piece of the puzzle.  Thanks.